# Element for picking an integer in MonoTouch.Dialog

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I have an application using the MonoTouch.Dialog Reflection API, and I have a view model with a couple of `int` properties. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like MonoTouch.Dialog have any elements supporting integer types. I would expect it to be a simple element that displays a `UIPicker` with a range of numbers. I'm aware that there is a `CounterElement` in the [monotouch-element-pack](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-element-pack), but it doesn't seem like it's possible to use it with the Reflection API. So the question is:

- Does an element fitting these requirements already exist?

Or if not

- Is it possible to extend the Reflection API with custom attributes for custom elements?
- Can one combine the Reflection API and the Element API?

Answer (score 1):

why not use a RadioElement with the list of valid integers?

```
var root = new RootElement ("Test") {
    new Section ("Count"){
            new RootElement ("Attendance", new RadioGroup ("Group", 2) {
                new Section () {
                    new RadioElement ("1", "1"),
                    new RadioElement ("2", "2"),
                    new RadioElement ("3", "3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The range of integers would be too large to use a radio group, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Then you're probably better off creating (or using someone else's) a custom element.  To do this with the reflection API, I believe that you have modify the source (I think just Reflect.cs)